# Checking whether a element present in List using mvel

Tags: java, ognl, mvel

I had a list with me. The list is like.

```
List<String> locations=new ArrayList<String>();
locations.add("California");
location.add("sydney");
location.add("Egypt");
```

Now I want to check in mvel whether this list contains California and Sydney. I thought I could use the below one but that is giving error.

```
     location contains "sydney","california"
```

How can I find whether a list contains multiple elements in mvel?

Comment: location contains "sydney" && location contains "California"

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer. I deleted so it won't mislead anyone else. mvel is java based, so why 'contains' wouldn't work?

Comment: Thanks Roflcoptr for your comment. But mvel permits following one: User (country== "IN" || = "US" || "CA") . Can't this kind of format is available  for checking elements in a list?

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
list.containsAll(["sydney", "california"])
```

Comment: https://github.com/mvel/mvel/blob/master/src/test/java/org/mvel2/tests/core/ComparisonTests.java

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
 //@Test
 public void testListContains() {
      List<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();

     locations.add("California");
     locations.add("sydney");
     locations.add("Egypt");

     String expression = "thelocations contains acity && thelocations contains anothercity";

     Map container = new HashMap();

     container.put("thelocations", locations);

     container.put("acity", "sydney");

     container.put("anothercity","California");

     Object result = MVEL.eval(expression,container);

     System.out.println(result);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify [kvn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19874279/1233652)'s answer, you can embed cities you testing against within the expression. Just surround it with single quotes:

```
public void testListContains() {
    List<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
    locations.add("California");
    locations.add("sydney");
    locations.add("Egypt");

    String expression = "thelocations contains 'sydney' && thelocations contains 'California'";

    Map container = new HashMap();
    container.put("thelocations", locations);

    Object result = MVEL.eval(expression,container);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```