# Evaluating MVEL expressions - ClassCastException

Tags: java, mvel

I am trying to evaluate an expression using Mvel java library. The expression is to check if a list contains a given string, but I am getting ClassCastException when ececuting the program. Below is the code snippet.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
import org.mvel2.MVEL;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by rakesh on 25-Nov-16.
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> evalParams = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz", "asd");
        evalParams.put("subType",list);
//        evalParams.put("contentType","Hotfixes");
        System.out.println();
//        System.out.println(MVEL.evalToBoolean("contentType == \"Hotfixes\" && \"abc\" in subType", evalParams));
        System.out.println(MVEL.evalToBoolean("\"abc\" in subType", evalParams));
    }
}
```

**Maven dependency details:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: syntax error or incompatable types]
[Near : {... "abc" in subType ....}]
                      ^
[Line: 1, Column: 10]
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.reduce(AbstractParser.java:2617)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.arithmeticFunctionReduction(AbstractParser.java:2522)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:147)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:47)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:288)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.evalToBoolean(MVEL.java:612)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.evalToBoolean(MVEL.java:657)
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.reduceNumeric(AbstractParser.java:2643)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.reduce(AbstractParser.java:2613)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Seems you're using the `in` expression wrong. It's supposed to be a projection, not a boolean test.

Comment: Okay, so if I have to check if a string is present in a list how can I do that using Mvel?

Comment: Google will tell you. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397191/checking-whether-a-element-present-in-list-using-mvel

Comment: Ah!! I was doing it the other way round! Thanks @Mark